# "git svn clone" chokes on moved directories?

Tags: git, git-svn

I've been trying to use **git svn clone** in order to use Git with SVN. I am running the clone command on the whole SVN repository and I chose to disable tracking the standard trunk/tags/branches layout.

However, the process of initial "git svn clone" operation always stops at the same revision (28) every time I run it:

*Connection reset by peer: Can't read from connection: Connection reset by peer at C:\Program Files\Git/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 5131*

The SVN log indicates that there were some **directories moved to another location** within the SVN repository in the previous revision (27).

I attempted to get on with the process by running "git svn fetch" afterwards but that fails as well. I am doing something wrong or is it a limitation of "git svn" command that it cannot handle moved directories?

I am on Windows, using the latest Git-1.7.4-preview20110204

Answer (score 2):

"Connection reset by peer" means that the SVN server closed the connection at this point. You can resume by issuing "git svn fetch" in the newly created directory.

Note that it is generally a good idea to tell git-svn about the repository layout -- otherwise, you end up with all branches and tags as copies of the code.

Comment: Tried various access protocols (svn://, http:// as well as local file://) and it gets always stuck at the very same revision, so it seems that it is not a network issue.